# Hyperledger Indy VonNetwork build

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-indy

I was following the documentation from https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain-Identity/indy-ssivc-tutorial to set up the demo project.
But I am stuck with the below error while creating the VON network. Can some one please give any hint on what is wrong with the set up [error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVnZY.png)

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try this installation on Ubuntu Operating system, if you are not using. In-fact, i also faced some error in installation on window but on Linux its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Hyperledger Indy SSI VC Demo with VON Network, TheOrgBook and Permitify Modules. VON Network is starting up properly. I am using MacOs. Python version is 3.6.3. Can you please share more details about the machine environment.